# Появляется какой-то дополнительный js скрипт при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

При загрузке страницы начал появляться какой-то дополнительный js файл копирующий мой js файл, только с измененным названием:

[image]

Внизу мой, сверху который подгружается. Адрес скрипта: debugger:///VM196 reg.js

Пытался найти как это отключить, не нашел.

Comment: Возможно, в браузере имеются какие-то плагины? Попробуйте повторить с отключёнными плагинами.

Comment: А что насчёт самого кода? Он выполняется два раза? ЗЫ: если ввести в консоль в хроме для примера `console.log('hello')`, то тогда выйдет похожий результат. Похоже, что это область в которой работает DevTools. Хотя я не уверен, с Chrome'ом не дружу .

Comment: @ΝNL993 там получается выполняются 2 файла, один мой и второй не мой. Я проверил еще в Яндексе, там появляется тот же скрипт и также выполняются 2 файла.

Comment: @ВикторКарев все расширения удалил, ничего не изменилось

Comment: На какой IDE работаете? Попробуйье комментироать подключение вашего скрипта, и запустить страничку. Удалите кеш в Chrome: Ctrl + F5

Comment: Это скрипт, который был изменен DevTools как-то (Вы нажали на кнопку "Pretty print" или ещё по какой-то причине). Формально этого файла нет, он виртуальный, отключить его тоже не выйдет) Можете, например, в саму консоль написать что-то для вывода - получите виртуальный файл с временным кодом (https://i.imgur.com/3mRFZZN.png, https://i.imgur.com/1QyQ0zo.png). Так что забейте лучше на это))

Comment: @VladimirGonchar А где эта кнопка "Pretty print"?

Comment: @GorkiiOgurec При открытии файла во вкладке "Sources" в нижней части редактора